# fread() download aborts after one gigabyte

Tags: php, file, download, buffer, fread

I'm currently having the problem that my download always stops at almost exactly one gigabyte. I have created a PHP download script which checks the user permissions before downloading and then prevents copying the URL. For this I use fread() to pass the data through PHP. However, I have no idea why the download always stops exactly after one gigabyte. The file is about twice as large.

Could someone take a look at this?

```
// ... Permission check, get download url, etc. ...

try 
{
    define('CHUNK_SIZE', 8 * 1024);

    function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = true) 
    {
        $buffer = '';
        $cnt    = 0;
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

        if ($handle === false) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        while (!feof($handle)) 
        {
            $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
            echo $buffer;

            if(ob_get_level() > 0)
            {
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }

            if ($retbytes) 
            {
                $cnt += strlen($buffer);
            }
        }

        $status = fclose($handle);

        if ($retbytes && $status) 
        {
            return $cnt;
        }

        return $status;
    }

    $mimetype = 'mime/type';
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $download->url);

    readfile_chunked($download->url);
} 
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Error while reading the file";
    exit;
}
```

**Update:**

I have now tested the script on another server. Here the download sometimes terminated after 300 MB and sometimes after 1.3 GB. I then defined the following settings:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "error.log");
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 7200);
```

On the other server, the script has now run through several times without any problems. The download was complete and the file was error-free. However, I copied these settings to the original system and the download still stops. I downloaded the file three times in a row. The file size varies slightly:

- 1.057.983 KB
- 1.056.192 KB
- 1.056.776 KB

I'm running out of ideas. What else could that be? They are both Apache web servers.

There are also no noticeable entries in the log.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at your php.ini settings - something like max_execution_time or the memory_limit may not be configured to allow for reading a large file like that.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you very much for your answer. memory_limit is set to 512M and max_execution_time is set to 120, which values would you recommend? And why does the download stop at exactly one gigabyte regardless of the download rate?